# simple_form bootstrap input

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm fairly new to html and erb and I'm having problems using customize simple_form.

I need to translate this html.erb input

```
<%= object.input :attribute, label: 'mylabel' %>
```

To this html input type

```
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label">mylabel</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
  <input class="form-control">
</div>
```

Comment: I think you should refer this https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/How-to-use-Bootstrap-3-input-group-in-Simple-Form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `:horizontal_forml` wrapper and `'form-horizontal'` class to `form`

```
<%= simple_form_for @post, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }, wrapper: :horizontal_form do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :attribute, label: 'mylabel' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Such wow. That's not what I was trying to do but it's actually way better, thanks.